# How to configure IntelliJ IDEA or WebStorm for a new JavaScript framework so that I can use intellisence?

Tags: intellij-idea, configuration, webstorm, intellisense

I'm trying a new JavaScript framework called Webix. When I'm developing a hello world application in IntelliJ IDEA with it, the intellisence feature doesn't work for the framework. How can I configure IntelliJ IDEA for new frameworks so that it can auto-complete stuff of the framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the basic cases, all you need to get intellisence is downloading the library files to your project or settings them up as external libraries (see [help article](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.2/configuring-javascript-libraries.html)).
For example, if a library is linked through the CDN link, you can use the **Download library**quick-fix  (call up with `Alt+Enter`) to load the file from the CDN link into the IDE cache:

[image]

Unfortunately this doesn't help in case if the library setup is too sophisticated for the static code analysis (when properties are added dynamically, etc.). In such cases, [typescript stubs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.2/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#ws_jsconfigure_libraries_ts_definition_files) can be used to enhance the completion, but *Webix* doesn't seem to provide any...
And, finally, recognizing custom web components created using this or that framework requires adding special support for the library, as the IDE needs a way to treat certain code constructions in a special way